# How to set context path to a variable in javascript

Tags: java, jsp

I have a variable named helpLocation in my js page.

like `var helpLocation = 'http://localhost:9080/App/webhelp/Home.htm';`

Here **App** is the Applciation Context.But it is hardcoded there. How can i set dynamically . I am trying to put as `<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>` and `var helpLocation = 'http://localhost:9080'+contextPath+'/webhelp/Home.htm';` . Then checked this with an alert as `alert(helpLocation);` but it is giving an alert with undefined

Comment: Use var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"; for setting context path.

Comment: Why aren't you using your var path for building you helpLocation?

Comment: like var helpLocation = 'http://localhost:9080/'+${path}+'/webhelp/Home.htm';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
```

for setting context path in a jsp page.And contextPath should be a global javascript variable.